# Add the search bar of google or any other search engine in my website

Tags: javascript, php, search-engine, google-search, google-search-api

i want to add the search bar of google or any other search engine with blank placeholder in my website and want to show the result in my website
will be better if i can apply CSS on it

[search bar should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1RkS.png)

Comment: You can only mask it by going though a third party email account.

Comment: Why use email at all? You can notify by email, then get them to follow a link to a "anonymous" chat/message area, you only need share public keys then..

Comment: Besides nothing anonymous about emails, ask Hillary.. ;p

Comment: i can imagine a system where the send\reply address is CODE@yourdomain.com and you pipe that to a script that resends it to the right person.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. How is the mail provider supposed to know where to send the emails if there's no returning address?

Something you could do, as suggested by the comments, is having user email addresses in your server and anonymize and then forward the messages that arrive there. Not really a trivial task.